# understanding charecteristics of transistors

Tags: transistors

1. While plotting input characteristics of a transistor, we choose to keep output voltage constant and plot the variation of input voltage and current. Why do we choose to keep output voltage constant and not current?
2. While plotting output characteristics of a transistor, we choose to keep input current constant and plot the variation of output voltage and current. Why do we choose to keep input current constant and not voltage?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: At one level it is convention, dating back to the days of tubes.  At another level, if you are looking at the input (output) characteristics, generally you would try to hold the output (input) characteristics constant to not overly confuse yourself.  Finally, in circuit design you usually get to define either input or output and figure it out from there.

Comment: While this question wold have a better home in EE it is not about convention but rather about what is easier to control and measure in an experiment. A bipolar junction transistor is a current (base) controlled current (collector) source, and it is natural to plot those parameters while keeping the collector-emitter voltage "constant" (in fact, not constant but uncontrolled). In contrast, a field effect transistor is a voltage (gate-source) controlled voltage (drain-source) source where the drain and gate currents are uncontrolled.

Answer (score 2):

What makes the transistor work as desired? Answer: Two VOLTAGES (Vbe and Vce). Hence, the output current Ic is just the **result** of these initial voltages.

1.) That is the reason to keep the voltage **Vce** constant during measurement of the input characteristics.

2.) For measuring the output characteristics we must keep the input bias constant. Here, we have two alternatives: Ib or Vbe. And both alternatives are in use (data sheets).

In contrast to former statements, the transistor is a voltage-controlled device. This can be (and has been) proven very often. As an example, explanation of the Early-effect as well as the well-known temperatute coefficient (dIc/dVbe=-2mV/K) are a clear indication of the voltage-control principle. There are numerous circuit examples which can be explained on the voltage control principle only.

Nevertheless, it is common practice to show the output set of curves for Ib=const. Why? Because only in this case the slopes of the different curves meet in the Early voltage, whichis a good description of the output conductances. And - as another advantage - the spacing between the several curves is nearly equal. But note, that this has only practical reasons - and has nothing to do with the physical working principle.

In contrary - keeping Ib=const offers the chance to see how an increase in Vce does act upon the VOLTAGE (resp. the E-field) across the B-E pn junction, which in turn gives a small Ic increase.

Comment: There was a down voting of my answer. In case, somebody does not "love" my answer, why not asking a question or presenting a counter argument?

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is that bipolar transistors are *current* devices.  When you talk about the gain of a bipolar transistor, you are talking about *current* gain.

For example, an ideal transistor with a Hfe of 100 will have a collector current of 100mA when 1mA is supplied to the base of that transistor.  Note that the actual voltage at both base and collector is irrelevant, so long as it allows those currents to flow.

Comment: Irrelevant? What about the Gummel-Poon model which describes how the current Ic depends on Vbe?

Comment: That the transistor just "will have a collector current of 100mA" when 1mA is supplied to the base is also misleading.